# Fazer cálculo usando LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em c#. Nele tenho três tabelas:

```
produto
{
    string idProduto;
    string descricao;
}

entrada
{
    string idProduto;
    int quant;
}

saida
{
    string idProduto;
    int quant;
}
```

e quero criar uma classe assim:

```
estoqueAtual
{
    string produto;
    int saldo; //onde saldo seria entrada.quant - saida.quant
}
```

Como posso fazer o cálculo do saldo?

Comment: Você poderia melhorar a sua pergunta? inserindo a informação de qual linguagem você está trabalhando e os produtos que tem na classe saida é os mesmo que tem na classe entrada?

Comment: pronto, já editei a pergunta

Comment: Acho que a melhor maneira seria deixar a variável `saldo` dentro de produto e não vejo, a princípio, a necessidade de uma classe pra `saída` e `entrada`. Você pode criar eles como métodos dentro de produto e, assim, eles atualizariam a variável de `saldo`.

Comment: É LINQ em memória, LINQ to SQL ou LINQ to Entities? Usa Entity Framework?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez uso Entity Framework

Comment: @leonardopessoa esse banco de dados será replicado, então estou preferindo apenas inserir informações do que editar, pra facilitar a hora de replicar pros outros bancos de dados

Comment: Mais dúvidas: você vai disparar esse cálculo manual ou ele vai ser reativo, por exemplo, feito como esse fosse uma *trigger*, mas dentro do código do C#? As "tabelas" estão mapeadas como *Models*? Se sim, você pode atualizar o código com os *Models*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não sei se entendi bem: assim que eu abrir o form, irei fazer o cálculo e listar em um grid. As tabelas estão mapeadas sim. Quanto a alterá-las, não sei se saberei fazer, pois estou aprendendo ainda.

Comment: Ok, sua aplicação é Windows Forms ou Web Forms? O cálculo ocorre na exibição da *grid* ou na inclusão/alteração da informação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

como você deu mais detalhes sobre o seu schema do banco de dados ou sobre o mapeamento das suas entidades, então fica difícil te entregar algo mais otimizado.

Então tente a seguinte consulta.:

```
var entradas = 
    from entrada in db.entradas
    group entrada.quant by entrada.idProduto into grupo
    select new { idProduto = grupo.Key, quant = grupo.Sum() };

var saidas = 
    from saida in db.saidas
    group saida.quant by saida.idProduto into grupo
    select new { idProduto = grupo.Key, quant = grupo.Sum() };

var estoque =
    from produto in db.produtos
    join entrada in entradas in produto.idProduto equals entrada.idProduto into leftEntradas
    from entrada in leftEntradas.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join saida in saidas in produto.idProduto equals saida.idProduto into leftSaidas
    from saida in leftSaidas.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new estoqueAtual {
        produto = produto.idProduto,
        saldo = (entrada?.quant ?? 0) + (saida?.quant ?? 0)
    };
```

Comment: Você pode me explicar essa linha: `group entrada.quant by entrada.idProduto into grupo` ?